# Joomla 1.7.2 Module configuration

Tags: joomla1.7

I am beginner with joomla. I have installed `joomla1.7.2` successfully. After that I uploaded a module name `MOD_MIXCLOUD_WIDGET`. To enable the module I go the `extention => plugin-manager` and enable the module.

How can I see the module in home page please some one help me when I click the `view-site` link in top?

Comment: Just `enable` wont work you need to assign that module a position &  the pages you want it to display.

Comment: Please tell me how can i create a page in joomla

Comment: Without reading docs it will not help you out. You really need to read Joomla docs & tutorial . http://docs.joomla.org/